# Use EC2 cloud-init startup script to launch a long-running task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I use my cloud-init startup script when my EC2 instance starts to install packages, pull code and then launch a long-running task, which may run for days:

```
su - username -c 'python /path/script.py'
```

Is this an issue for cloud-init if the script stays stuck for days at this line?
And if so what is the best way to let the script run while permitting the cloud-init script to end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was not an issue to have a cloud-init script running for hours. AWS does not seem to have a mechanism in place to kill cloud-init scripts that have not terminated after a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the best way to let the script run while permitting the cloud-init script to end?

I'd use the 'at' command, e.g.

```
echo "python /path/script.py"|at now +3 minutes
```

the script will be run in 3 minutes after that command, and cloud-init script will continue to run without waiting for script.py.

There may be trouble with `su`, so it'd be simpler to run the script from the root, of course if it is acceptable.